# Where can I find the Copyright information of .rpm file?

Tags: centos, rpm, source, licenses

I can see the licence information about rpm file by executing below:

```
rpm -qip {rpmfilename}.rpm
```

but there is no information about copyright holder.

Is there any easy way to know who has the copyright of specific rpm package?

Should I download the corresponding source file and read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no easy way as the RPM file specifications (see e.g. [here](https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/)) do not include a tag to advertise the copyright holder, only the license type.

It would seem that the only somewhat "scriptable" way relies on the contained files labelled as documentation, which you can list via

```
rpm -qpd {rpmfilename}.rpm
```

in the hope that the RPM packager included a "copyright" file there (see examples [here](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html)), but this is not guaranteed. Even then, you would still need to extract that part of the RPM to actually access the content of that file - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787375/how-do-i-extract-the-contents-of-an-rpm) on how that can be done: essentially

```
rpm2cpio filename.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

In the end, you may well have to look at the source code; if you are lucky, it is hosted on GitHub, and you can find information on the copyright holder on the project page.

Comment: I didn't know that I can extract rpm files. I'll try it, thank you for your answer.

Comment: note that modern packages have a tag for license files and you can print them using `rpm -qpL {rpmfilename}.rpm`

Comment: Thanks, I tried `rpm -qpL` but it showed nothing about most of packages.